# Why is there a file called [ in my /usr/bin directory?

Tags: files, filesystems

Recently back to Linux from another operating system I noticed a file called [ which seems strange to me.  What is it for?

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin | head -2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       39552 Nov  3 14:44 [
```

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Could you undelete your other question about chmod? It actually has quite an interesting answer even though it isn't doing quite what you thought it was.

Answer (score 7):

The command `[` is another "name" for the command `test`, so that the syntax of `if` constructs look nicer. These two are equivalent:

```
if test "$x" -eq 0

if [ "$x" -eq 0 ]
```

The final `]` is only syntactic sugar. The equivalence is mostly just a historic feature.

Note that the newer test construct `[[ ... ]]` (which is non-standard) is part of the shell syntax, as opposed to being a command.

Answer (score 0):

`[` is a command, to ensure you can use `type [`

It says it's a shell builtin command, or if you use `type -a [` you will see that there is another `[` under `/usr/bin/` directory.

You can see it's help with `help [` command.

**USAGE:** It's another form of `if` in bash, For example:

`[ "Hello" == "Helo" ] ; echo $?`

Comment: That's useful to know but that still doesn't explain why there is a file called [ as well.

Comment: @codemagician: To allow you to run the `[` command.

Comment: (a) "It says ...." What says? (b) If it's built into the shell, why is it a file?

Comment: @TRIG - (a) "It" refers to `type [` as being the shell builtin - (b) `type -a [` is the file; they are two different executables

Comment: @Sepahrad Salour - I wouldn't call it another form of `if` - `[ ... ]` is a condition tester (generates true/false), whereas `if` determines which action to perform depending on a true/false value given to it.